# Deleting treenodes in treeview without deleting their children in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I am trying to delete one specific node in a treeview in c#. It is supposed to do the following:

Let's say "root-->path1-->path1.1-->path1.2" is one of the paths in the treeview. When deleting the node "path1", it is supposed to delete only this node and not also "path1.1" and "path1.2". The root node is supposed to become parent of these two nodes.

So far I used this code which deletes the node with all its children:

```
treeView1.Nodes.Remove(node);
```

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Change those nodes' parent before deleting their current parent.

Comment: That was my first thought, too, but the parent property is read only

Comment: To change a node's parent, you should add it to `Nodes` collection of another node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change those nodes' parent before deleting their current parent. For example:

```
var selected = this.treeView1.SelectedNode;
TreeNodeCollection container;
if (selected.Parent == null)
    container = treeView1.Nodes;
else
    container = selected.Parent.Nodes;
var list = selected.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().ToList();
foreach (TreeNode n in list)
{
    n.Remove();
    container.Add(n);
}
selected.Remove();
```