# remove parent without child in treeview c#

Tags: c#, treeview, removechild

i want to remove parent that their children dont have tag in treeview in c#
what should ido?
i use this code but dont remove all empty node

```
  public static void removeParentWithNoLayer(TreeView tree)
    {
        void process(TreeNodeCollection parent)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < parent.Count; i++)
            {
                TreeNode child = parent[i];
                var data = child.Tag;
                if (child.Nodes.Count == 0 & child.Tag == null)
                {
                tree.Nodes.Remove(child);


                }
                process(child.Nodes);
            }

        }
        process(tree.Nodes);

    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting treenodes in treeview without deleting their children in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49870018/deleting-treenodes-in-treeview-without-deleting-their-children-in-c-sharp)

Comment: thanks for reply, but this is not what i want !!

Comment: i want to delete parent nodes that children dont have tag

Comment: What is this? `if (child.Nodes.Count == 0 & child.Tag == null)` You mean `&&`.

Comment: yes, i mean &&.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with a Do-While:

```
int contador=0;

private void EliminaParentsWithoutChilds()
{
            
    do
    {
        contador = 0;

        foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
        {
            RemoveEmptyNodes(node);
        }

    } while (contador > 0);
}

private void RemoveEmptyNodes(TreeNode node)
{
    if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.Nodes)
        {
            RemoveEmptyNodes(childNode);
        }
    }
    else
    {       
        node.Remove();
        contador++;
    }
}
```